# PHP - Display Content in Json with Specific File Extension & Huge Records

Tags: php, json

As a PHP developer i am stuck. My mobile app developer needs an API where my PHP code will return only **imagenames** from a folder with following twist

1) There are almost 15,000 images in **wp-content/uploads/2015/04** folder, which times out the page.

What i have tried is following code which works great, if there are less number of images in that folder.What should i do in this case.

```
<?php

$dir          = "wp-content/uploads/2015/04";
$return_array = array();

if(is_dir($dir)){

    if($dh = opendir($dir)){
        while(($file = readdir($dh)) != false){

            if($file == "." or $file == ".."){

            } else {
                $return_array[] = $file; // Add the file to the array
            }
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($return_array);
}

?>
```

Comment: Ever heard of `substr()` ?

Comment: @Daan i figure out the file extension part, need help on second question

Comment: Don't you have the filenames in a database or something?

Comment: Set 'set_time_limit(0)' on top on the page so your code execution will not stop because of time limit.

Comment: unfortunately no the filenames are not in the database

Comment: are you sure this is the only thing you do in the loop? you mentioned file extensions earlier. readdir seem to be the fastest way to iterate files.

Comment: @zedd i sorted the file extension. the only problem now is to get the timeout sorted

Comment: @user580950 does "sorted" mean that there is more code in your real example? that could be whats slow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend setting the php time limit to be higher using set_time_limit().

Also, try caching the results in a database or file, so you don't have to do an expensive lookup every time.

An alternative to opendir which might be faster would be to use the shell's "ls" command (note that this would be OS-specific, so reduce code portability).

For example:

```
echo json_encode(explode("\n", trim(`ls -1 wp-content/uploads/2015/04`)));
```